# MYSQL Query in MYSQL 10.1.19-MariaDB and PHP 7 Returns No Results

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Going from MYSQL 5.1.73cll to MYSQL 10.1.19-MariaDB (and now running in PHP 7) this query goes from returning GOOD results to returning NO results.

```
SELECT t.eventid, t.tname, t.tdate, t.tyear, a.aname, t.ttour FROM 
gs_tournaments as t LEFT JOIN gs_active as a ON a.eventid = t.eventid LEFT 
JOIN gs_stats as s ON s.tid = t.tid WHERE s.pid = 34062 && a.active = 'y' 
GROUP BY t.eventid ORDER BY t.tid ASC
```

I have searched other MYSQL upgrade posts but don't see an answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try left outer join rather than left join?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - still no results

Comment: I will suggest to try first with only the gs_tournaments table to see if you get result, then add the first LEFT JOIN and then the second. I'm using 10.1.25-MariaDB with PHP7 and I've seen no difference with MySQL. Strange.

Comment: Thanks Peter. That debugging advice led me to the problem in another area of the code. Thank you!

Comment: You may provide the answer on your own, may be that'S helpful for others...

Answer (score 0):

Thw answer is to carefully walk back the query until you find what is breaking it, or in this case returning no results. In my case it was narrowing it down to the 'WHERE s.pid = 34062' which was a condition that was never met. This was due to the value 34062 being calculated incorrectly in another part of the code.
So lesson learned - carefully eliminate conditions or tests until you find the cuplprit. -- Ed